# Boost Thread Check Whether Current Thread's Is Equal To Another Native Handle

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

I know the headline sounds weird, so let me explain. I have a variable `bob` that's a `boost::thread::native_handle_type` and assigned with a native handle. Now I want to check if the currently running process is the same as the one assigned to bob. I'm not responsible for the design of the program, so the situation to check for this comparision is unfortunately inevitable since this quite a big project.

Anyway, so I'm looking for something like this:

`boost::this_thread::native_handle() == bob` or
`boost::this_thread::get_id() == bob.get_id()`

Is that possible somehow? Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.
although I think you are misunderstanding here :

> Now I want to check if the currently running process is the same as the one assigned to bob

Compare the thread id.

with the native handle on windows:[`GetThreadId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683233%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
On mac and posix I think you have a `pthread_t  *`  as handle. This type is the id of the thread. You can compare it with `pthraed_equal` i think see [here](http://students.cs.byu.edu/~cs460ta/cs460/labs/pthreads.html)

So you answer is compare the native id type with platform dependant code.

If fact the main issue is that the native id types are not the same on the 2 platforms.

Comment: How can I acquire the thread_id from a native handle? I only have the native handle `bob`, so the critical part would be the `bob.get_id()`.

Comment: I was afraid that this was the only option. ;) Of course I'm looking for a cross platform implementation, since my job right now is to get rid of as many platform dependent bits as possible. Thanks for your help! (I hope I'll figure out another way though ;))

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. You cannot get the native handle for the currently running thread, and Boost.Thread doesn't let you get the ID based on a native handle.

Either somehow change `bob` so that it has a `thread::id` available, or fall back to native code.

Comment: This sums up my concerns. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Both are equivalent, but the == and != operators are marked as "backward compatible" meaning that you should not use them

```
// backwards compatibility
bool operator==(const thread& other) const;
bool operator!=(const thread& other) const;
```

The implementation of these operators shows that they use the ID to compare:

```
inline bool thread::operator==(const thread& other) const
{
    return get_id()==other.get_id();
}

inline bool thread::operator!=(const thread& other) const
{
    return get_id()!=other.get_id();
}
```